# Changing the OpenID provider

Tags: openid, identity-management

So far I have been using [MyOpenID](https://www.myopenid.com/) as an OpenID provider. Now it announced that it will close down and I will need a new provider.

Is there any way to transfer all registrations to the new account or will I have to do it site by site?

Comment: You probably already did this, but this would be a good opportunity to set up [delegation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/using-your-own-url-as-your-openid/). This way, you can change your provider with very little effort.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the myOpenID accounts are migrated/redirected to another identity-provider, then it will be site-by-site because when you try to log into a site, it will contact your OpenID provider for credentials and identity information. If the site is shut down, then it will not be able to respond to the request.

You should, only have to select a new identity-provider at each site; you shouldn’t have to enter any new information (assuming of course, that you have already entered your information at the new provider). However, you do have to go to each one to specify your new OpenID provider at each one individually. You’ll also need to authorize each site with the new provider, but that’s just an extra click.

Comment: Ironic that the goal was/is to simplify registration-management by using a central identity, but really, nothing has changed; you still have to go to each site and change your login information. I suppose one solution could be if you could go to the identity-provider’s site and have it contact each site registered with it and send them information about your new provider; sort of like having your old doctor send your medical record to the new one.

Comment: That's why you should set up OpenID delegation. [It's not exactly rocket science](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/using-your-own-url-as-your-openid/). It took me longer to register with the new provider than to change the delegation URL I use for various services.

Comment: That’s a good point, and [myOpenID does support delegation](https://www.myopenid.com/help#own_domain), but that only helps if you both have a domain (which you will maintain indefinitely) and have used it to registr. I suspect that Tim has been using myOpenID as the server, so he’ll have to change each one. If he has a domain that he can set up and use from now on, then he would only have to change them all once. (An update-all-site function would still be handy in this situation.)